# How into inject javascript frameworks into ChakraBridge context?

Tags: javascript, win-universal-app, chakra

I am trying to use math.js in my UWP app using ChakraBridge library. I referred the following link to use a javascript framework in a UWP app.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1060634/Using-JavaScript-frameworks-from-your-Csharp-UWP-a

But I am unable to figure out how to inject a javascirpt framework into Chakra context. The link says use the method "ReadAndExecute" or "DownloadAndExecute", but I could not find those methods in any of the classes of ChakraBridge library.
So how do I inject *.js files into ChakraBridge context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The link says use the method "ReadAndExecute" or "DownloadAndExecute", but I could not find those methods in any of the classes of ChakraBridge library.

The two methods should be defined by coder. They are documented in [ChakraBridge GitHub Site](https://github.com/deltakosh/JsBridge). And they look like below:

```
async Task ReadAndExecute(string filename)
{
    //"js" is the folder name of your javascript library.
    var script = await CoreTools.GetPackagedFileContentAsync("js", filename);
    host.RunScript(script);
}

async Task DownloadAndExecute(string url)
{
    var script = await CoreTools.DownloadStringAsync(url);
    host.RunScript(script);
}
```

So, to register *.js files into ChakraBridge context. Simply call these two methods like below:

```
string url = @"http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/3.2.1/math.js";
await DownloadAndExecute(url);//load math.js from remote source.
await ReadAndExecute("math.js");//load math.js from local source.
await ReadAndExecute("main.js");//main.js is the custom js codes. You can utilize math.js here.
```

And here is the link to a basic demo I made:[ChakraBridgeSample](https://github.com/elvisxia/ChakraBridgeSample)

Notes:

1. Newtonsoft.Json should be referenced in your project as pre-work. It can be installed either through Searching on Nuget Package Manager or by Nuget Package Manager Console: "Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json".
2. The behavior of registering CommunicationManager.OnObjectReceived event is a little different from GitHub Documentation. There is no Type argument anymore(only data argument). So in javascript side,sendToHost function should look like below:

   ```
   var data = math.atan2(3, -3) / math.pi;
   // "Double" should match the typeof(Double) in C# side. Capitalizing is necessary.
   sendToHost(JSON.stringify(data), "Double");
   ```